# Git - push current branch shortcut

Tags: git

Is there a shortcut to tell Git to push the current tracking branch to origin?

**Note:** I know that I can change the [default push behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/138585), but I am looking for an ad-hoc solution that does not change the default behavior.

For example, suppose I am on branch `feature/123-sandbox-tests` I would be using

```
git push origin feature/123-sandbox-tests
```

which is tedious. I am looking for a shortcut, something like

```
git push origin current # <- example, not working
```

where git knows that current is `feature/123-sandbox-tests`.

---

**Edit**: Starting from version 2.0, git's **default** behavior has changed to a more intuitive behavior, which is what I wanted to achieve. See [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0) for details.

**Edit 2**: [ceztko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20922141/138585) is the best answer as it allows to push the current branch, regardless of the settings.

Answer (score 865, accepted):

According to [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-codegitpushoriginHEADcode) documentation:

```
git push origin HEAD
    A handy way to push the current branch to the same name on the remote.
```

So I think what you need is `git push origin HEAD`. Also it can be useful `git push -u origin HEAD` to set upstream tracking information in the local branch, if you haven't already pushed to the origin.

Comment: I prefer this over setting push.default to simple or current, because different machines could have different settings. You may get used to `git push` only pushing the current branch, but on other machines, you may accidentally push all matching branches.

Comment: @wisbucky I have several aliases, including `co`, so if I were to try to even pull down and then check out code without my `~/.gitconfig` file on that VM, I'll know it immediately. That lets me feel pretty safe about changing the push default to `upstream`.

Comment: Interesting that this doesn't work with just `@`, which is documented as a valid alias to `HEAD`. (e.g. `git push -u origin @`)

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706402/850996 is a more correct answer for the question in the OP

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada well, the OP edited the question stating "ceztko's answer is the best answer as it allows to push the current branch, **regardless of the settings**"

Answer (score 259):

You can **configure git** to push to the current branch using the following command

```
git config --global push.default current
```

then just do

```
git push
```

this will push the code to your current branch.

Comment: Does it make sense to add `push = refs/heads/current:refs/for/master/current` to a 'remote' section in .git/config ? That is, is 'current' a special word here? Or will it be looking for a branch called "current"?

Comment: @DavidDoria 'current' is not a branch named here.

Comment: Best do `git push -u origin feature_branch_name` to set up upstream/tracking! If you use a remote repository at least.

Comment: I can't imagine a workflow in which "push master even when I'm not on master" is a sane default. I guess if master isn't an important branch and you're fine with whatever untested, un-reviewed, probably-insecure garbage ending up on it, then I guess these defaults aren't *harmful*, but for any other workflow this default seems dangerous.

Answer (score 47):

You should take a look to a similar question in [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Basically it explains how to set the default behavior to push your current branch just executing `git push`. Probably what you need is:

`git config --global push.default current`

Other options:

- **nothing** : Do not push anything
- **matching** : Push all matching branches
- **upstream**/**tracking** : Push the current branch to whatever it is tracking
- **current** : Push the current branch

Answer (score 14):

I use such alias in my .bashrc config

```
alias gpb='git push origin `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`'
```

On the command `$gpb` it takes the current branch name and pushes it to the origin.

Here are my other aliases:

```
alias gst='git status'
alias gbr='git branch'
alias gca='git commit -am'
alias gco='git checkout'
```

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, the ultimate shortcut:

In my `.bash_profile` I have `alias push="git push origin HEAD"`, so whenever i type `push` I know I'm pushing to the current branch I'm on.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using git 1.7.x, you can run the following command to set the remote tracking branch.

```
git branch --set-upstream feature/123-sandbox-tests origin/feature/123-sandbox-tests
```

Then you can simply use `git push` to push all the changes. For a more complete answer, please see the [accepted answer to a similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

If you only want to push the current branch with the push command, then you can change the push behaviour to upstream:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Comment: Thanks, however in this case wouldn't ALL tracking branches be pushed to origin?

Comment: I have modified the answer, please see the link, the answer is more complete there.

Comment: Again, the problem is that all branches the are tracking branches are being pushed that way. As I wrote in my question the branch is a tracked branch in the first place, so I think that setting the upstream branch as you suggested is redundant. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Then you can configure git to push only the current branch by changing the git push behaviour. `git config --global push.default upstream` will set the push behaviour to push only the current branch.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way: run `git push -u origin feature/123-sandbox-tests` once. That pushes the branch the way you're used to doing it and also sets the upstream tracking info in your local config. After that, you can just `git push` to push tracked branches to their upstream remote(s).

You can also do this in the config yourself by setting `branch.<branch name>.merge` to the remote branch name (in your case the same as the local name) and optionally, `branch.<branch name>.remote` to the name of the remote you want to push to (defaults to origin). If you look in your config, there's most likely already one of these set for `master`, so you can follow that example.

Finally, make sure you consider the `push.default` setting. It defaults to "matching", which can have undesired and unexpected results. Most people I know find "upstream" more intuitive, which pushes only the current branch.

Details on each of these settings can be found in the [git-config man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

**On second thought,** on re-reading your question, I think you know all this. I think what you're actually looking for doesn't exist. How about a bash function something like (untested):

```
function pushCurrent {
  git config push.default upstream
  git push
  git config push.default matching
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of ceztko's answer I wrote this little helper function to make my life easier:

```
function gpu()
{
    if git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u} > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        git push origin HEAD
    else
        git push -u origin HEAD
    fi
}
```

It pushes the current branch to origin and also sets the remote tracking branch if it hasn't been setup yet.