# "git push" and "git push --tags" in the same command?

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

I usually run:

```
git push
git tag v4.7
git push --tags
```

Both the first and third operations connect to the server, which wastes time.
I want to make it faster by pushing only once. What command(s) would achieve this?
It is in a bash [script](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/blob/v2.0.2-dev/tools/release.sh#L45), and needs to run fine in any branch, not just `master`.

Reading the manual, I don't think `git push all` is the solution:

> --all: Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under refs/heads/ be pushed.
>
> --tags: All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line.

Comment: what about `git push --tags HEAD`?

Comment: HEAD means the current branch, so I can use it as a "refspec explicitly listed" indeed! Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745135/push-git-commits-tags-simultaneously

Answer (score 37):

The closest option may be:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

> Push all the refs that would be pushed without this option, and also push annotated tags in refs/tags that are missing from the remote but are pointing at
>              committish that are reachable from the refs being pushed.

Comment: That sounds like a valid solution as well... How is it different from `git push --tags HEAD`?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Like `git push` it also pushes other tracking branches (depends on `push.default` configuration), not just `HEAD`, and it pushes tags on pushed branches, not all tags.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. AFAIK `git push` only pushes the current branch.

Comment: Note that `--follow-tags` will only push *annotated* tags (though often this is what you want anyway).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, `git push` *without explicit refspecs passed to it* behaves according to the `push.default` configuration variable, which, if absent, currently defaults to `matching`.

Comment: As of git 2.0, the default if `push.default` is not set is set to `simple` which pretty much means the current branch. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0)

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation of `--tags` you can specify additional refspecs to be pushed.

So you can simply use

```
git push --tags origin HEAD
```

Comment: This does not appear to work: "fatal: 'HEAD' does not appear to be a git repository".  `git push origin HEAD --tags` works, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can create alias to have a fast access to this command:

```
git config --global alias.p '!git push && git push --tags'
```

or

```
git config --global alias.pa '!git push --all && git push --tags'
```

now you can do it like this:

```
git tag v4.7
git p
```

You can read more about aliases [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

Comment: Interesting tip, but that does not reduce the number of requests made to the server, right? As explained in the question it is for a bash script, so my question is not about typing less.

Answer (score 1):

Since Git 2.4, you can use the following command to push tags and commits at the same time:

```
git push --atomic origin <branch name> <tag>
```

The following command push the commits to origin master branch together with tag reference tag-name: v4.7  .

```
git tag v4.7 -a -m "This the best atomic version ever"
git push --atomic origin master tag-name
```

See eg [Push git commits & tags simultaneously SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250) ,  [Git - Push Tags and Commits Atomically](https://kontext.tech/article/698/git-push-tags-and-commits-atomically) , [git-push docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)