# how come running git branch 'branchname' the branch does not appear on the github website

Tags: git, github, version-control

how come running git branch branchname the branch does not appear on the github website and why cant i push to a branch that i made locally. I have done this:

```
git clone https://github.com/myname/myrep.git 
git branch gitcheat
git checkout  gitcheat
git branch

* gitcheat
  master
```

i tried

```
git push gitcheat gitcheat
```

but i got

```
fatal: 'gitcheat' does not appear to be a git repository
```

How do i get my local branch to be stored online in the git repo as a branch so i can push and pull to it like i do with the master branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
git push -u origin gitcheat
```

origin is the name of your upstream repo url: `https://github.com/myname/myrep.git`

I prefer adding myname in the server part, in order to only have to enter my password when pushing back:

```
git remote set-url origin https://myname@github.com/myname/myrep.git
```

That will be for the first push only: after, a simple `git push` will be enough, see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Make sure your [`push.default` policy is set properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27216212/6309):

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

Comment: when i delete my local branch the one on github website remains intact, do i have to delete it manually always or is there a better way. also what does the -u do in the push command

Comment: the -u (illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309) does set an upstream branch (meaning your local branch knows where to push to: `origin/gitcheat`. It tracks it: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309). And yes, deleting a branch is a local operation: you need to push that deletion: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309: `git push origin --delete gitcheat`