# git push origin branchname always pushes to master

Tags: git, git-push

I've searched a bit, but can't seem to find the answer.

On two the boxes I have access to, when I do a "git push --dry-run origin mytestbranch", I get the following result:

```
To git@bitbucket.org:rien/test.git
 * [new branch]      test -> test
```

However, on my macbook, when I try the same command, I get the following result:

```
To git@bitbucket.org:rien/test.git
   417248a..cf7d564  test -> master
```

Only when I explicitly say push to the test origin branch (`git push --dry-run origin test:test`) does it work as expected.

How do I change it so that a basic `git push --dry-run bb test` will push to a newly created remote branch and not to master?

I created the test branch on both boxes with a `git checkout -b test origin/master`

Edited to add: 
- both branches have a `git config push.default` set to `tracking`.

I specifically want to know how to configure git so that when i type `git push origin test` that it acts the same as `git push origin test:test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if there is a difference in **[push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21772695/6309)**:

```
git config push.default
```

I suspect on the first box, the push is "simple"

```
git config push.default simple
```

Check also the **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)** of the test branch on the second branch:

```
git config branch.test.merge
```

On the second branch, it might not be defined (hence the default value master)

You [can set it explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309):

```
git checkout test
git branch -u origin/test
# or
git push -u origin test:test
```

The [OP rien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4331302/rien) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329500/git-push-origin-branchname-always-pushes-to-master/27329538?noredirect=1#comment43127662_27329538):

> After noticing I had a different version of git for those boxes, I looked around some more and found that if I set the **`push.default`** to **`simple`** or `matching` for the git version 1.9.3, the `git push origin test` works as expected.
>   It seems like the `tracking` `push.default` is deprecated for this version of git so it did not understand it.

Comment: For both boxes, when I type `git config push.default'`, the result is `tracking`.

On the second branch, the result of `git config branch.test.merge` is `refs/heads/master` and nothing on the first branch.

However, when I try to set it explicitly, I receive the following error:
`error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/test' does not exist`.  How do I change it so that when I create a branch with `git checkout -b test origin/master` that the default `git push origin test` behavior is `git push origin test:test` ?

Comment: Simply do a git push -u origin test:test

Comment: I understand I can do that.   I'd more specifically like to know how I can configure  git so the default behavior of `git push origin test` behaves the same way as `git push -u origin test:test`.

Comment: It will behave that way: only the first push needs to use the -u option: see my explanations at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309

Comment: Could you explain why in the first push for the first box I'm on, I wouldn't need to specify `git push -u origin test:test` then and `git push origin test` works?  Why do I need to specify this on my second box (my macbook) specifically?  Why does it work differently and how do I configure the second box (my mac) to work the same as the first box?

Comment: @rien is the git version the same on both boxes?

Comment: The one that works as expected has "git version 1.8.2.1", the other one has "git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)".

Comment: After noticing I had a different version of git for those boxes, I looked around some more and found that if I set the `push.default` to `simple` or `matching` for the git version 1.9.3, the `git push origin test` works as expected.  It seems like the `tracking` `push.default` is deprecated for this version of git so it did not understand it.   Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @rien great feedback! i have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @rien - `tracking` is not deprecated, it still works as of 2.2.0, it is now an undocumented synonym for `upstream`.

Comment: @AndrewC In that case, why is it that typing `git push origin test` with a `push.default` set to `tracking` result in a different behavior between git versions 1.8.2.1 and 1.9.3?  In 1.8.2.1, the command will create a new branch `test` on `origin` while in 1.9.3, the command will merge the branch into `master`.

Comment: @rien - possibly you have a different setting in your repository config file (.git/config) that is shadowing a setting in your ~/.gitconfig ? Or maybe it's because you are manually specifying the ref on the command line - with tracking set I just type `git push` and it knows I want to push my current branch to the upstream.