# ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward) on a new up-to-date branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, fast-forward

In my repo, I have a `master` branch, and a `new` branch.

I've been working on `new` for a while, making commits, and pushes as I go. I decided now to branch off `new` and call it `newest`. So I did

```
git checkout -b "newest"
```

and the branch was successfully created. I added a file, and started working on it. I committed my changes a couple of times.

BUT when I try to push this new branch and my changes to it to `origin`, I get this error:

```
C:\wamp\www\myproj>git push origin
To https://github.com/Imray/Proj.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        new -> new (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Imray/Proj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So, as specified in the instructions, I tried `git pull`, but then I got:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> newest
```

I'm stuck.

How do I push my new branch and the changes to `github`?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `git config push.default`. It might be on "`matching`", since it tries to push all existing branches.
That was the [default before Git 2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21772695/6309).

I would recommend setting it to "`simple`", in order to push only the current branch.

That being said, to push a branch, you need (for the first push) to setup an **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)**.

For a branch never pushed before:

```
git push -u origin newest
```

For a branch which does exists on the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/new new
```

Then a `git checkout master ; git pull would` work.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

- git pull --rebase https://github.com/yours master/name of your branch

hope it helps