# Git push confusion -- what does "simple" mean?

Tags: git, push

```
In Git 2.0 the default has been changed to simple which is narrower in scope – more specific and more intuitive – it will now only push:

The current branch to the branch with the same name only when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote branch on the same remote;

The current branch to the branch with the same name, if you are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
```

I'm confused about this.  What does "the current branch is set to integrate with that remote branch" mean?  I'm working on a feature branch I created locally.  When I run "git push", will it push my branch to the remote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in Git 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13148066/3755692)

Comment: It means that it will only push the branch you're on, and only push it to the most intuitive place. Older versions of git would try to push a lot more branches, causing extra work to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find documentation on `push.default` [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

`simple` is intended to be the 'probably does what you want' default in newer git versions. It's a halfway-house between `current` and `upstream`.

Let's assume that you're working on a branch called `foo`.

`current` means that if you either tell git to push to the place you normally pull from (`git push` or `git push origin`), or if you tell it to push to some other remote repository (`git push somewhere_else`), it will push a branch called `foo` to a remote branch also called `foo`. This means that `git push` will be interpreted as `git push origin foo:foo`.

`upstream` means that if you tell git to push to the place you normally pull from, it will push the branch to whatever remote branch it is tracking - i.e. the branch that you get updates from when you pull. You can find this in the `config` file inside the repository's `.git` folder. For example, if it contains the section

```
[branch "foo"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/bar
```

then that means that a straightforward `git push` when you've got branch `foo` checked out will push to `origin/bar`, so it's equivalent to `git push origin foo:bar`.

`upstream` only makes sense when you're pushing to the place you pull from. If your local branch isn't tracking an upstream branch, nothing will happen (though git will suggest a single line push-and-start-tracking command, see below).

`simple` does the same as `upstream` when you push to the place you normally pull from, and does the same as `current` if you're pushing somewhere else.

Now, you mentioned in your post that you're dealing with a local branch, which presumably means it's not tracking anything on the remote end. You can push a branch and make it track the place it was pushed to with the following:

```
git push --set-upstream origin foo:bar
```

Leaving out the `:bar` will make it push to a branch with the same name as the local branch.