# Publishing branches with GitHub for Windows fails with no upstream branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, github-for-windows

When I try to publish a new local branch using Github for Windows the process fails without an error message. Opening the shell and using `'git push'` results in the error:

```
fatal: The current branch local-branch-name has no upstream branch
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin local-branch-name
```

If I cut and paste this command the push goes forward and I can use the GUI for all other pushes and pulls. I have been using GitHub for Windows for more than a year and this just started. I recently upgraded and I am running version **Great Dane 2.6.4.1**. I don't know if that has any relevance or not. I am not seeing a lot of reports or really any reports of this type of issue.

Did I set a flag somewhere that is causing this? Did a GitHub default change? what could be causing this behaviour? (I fully expect this to be a PEBKAC issue I just don't know what I did).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in Git 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to call a specific upstream or set a default upstream setting.

```
 $ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
 $ git remote -v
       origin   https://github.com/mjbrender/simple-blog.git (fetch)
       origin   https://github.com/mjbrender/simple-blog.git (push)
```

If you don't have one set yet:

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com/some-maintainer/some-project.git
```

You can keep yourself from having to this again after a project clone with this:

```
$ git config --global push.default simple
```

Comment: Using what exactly? Did that help?

Comment: _sorry that was half a comment - don't know what happened to the rest_
I updated my config using 
`$ git config --global push.default simple`
but it had no effect. I am still unable to publish new local branches via the Github for Windows GUI.

Comment: You are unable to publish new local branches via Github for Windows GUI on a project that you cloned prior to running the `git config --global push.default simple` command?  Try re-cloning after running that command, branching, then publishing.