# Git Local Repository All Steps

Tags: git, git-push

I am zero in git. Absolute zero. So there are many materials and hints on the web, however I cannot put them together.

So could some one please tell me what I have done wrong and what else I should do to achieve what I am looking for?

What I want to do is simple. I have written a project in C++ and now I want to make a local repository to have version control of all my changes. That is all I need.

I have a folder:

```
~/myproject
```

which contains my project files. and another folder to save changes inside (my local place to store changes)

```
~/my-local-repository
```

So, first of all, I have set up a repo:

```
cd ~/myproject
git init
```

then I created a .gitignore :

```
cd ~/myproject
touch .git/.gitignore
```

and excluded my `bin` directory.

then I added a few files

```
git add this that
```

then I removed them

```
git reset
```

and again added some files. I changed some files and commit:

```
git commit -am "new change"
```

Then setting a dummy username and email:

```
git config user.name "my.phd"
git config user.email myphd@exmaple.com
```

Then I set the local repository folder for local changes:

```
git remote add local ~/my-local-repository
```

so I expect all my changes go here.

Now, when I push:

```
git push local
```

I get this error:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

fatal: '/media/doc/my-local-repository' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Maybe this error is very simple to many people. But I understand nothing out of it. What have I done wrong till now and how to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in Git 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0)

Comment: @Pierre-Jean i dont understand that solution

Comment: @Pierre-Jean, the other link addresses the warning, but not the fatal error.

Comment: My bad, you're right @tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on the line

```
'/media/doc/my-local-repository' does not appear to be a git repository
```

That folder doesn't have a git repo in it. You need to run

```
git init
```

in it. If you are working in a new local branch, you will also have to push that new branch upstream to have it appear in the remote. To do that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repo-and-track-it-too) question.

Comment: just want to make sure. `git init` must be run on the source code folder or the storage folder?

Comment: @ar2015: Both. Both folders need to be git repositories

Comment: i did that on both. this time i got this error
`No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '/media/doc/my-local-repository'`

Comment: You still need to push your current branch upstream. See the link I posted.

Comment: seems worked. did it? i still did not understand what happened. [message](http://pastebin.com/jRJSZZij)

Comment: @ar2015. It worked. Git requires local and remote repositories to be git repositories. Individual branches created in a local repo will not get pushed up to the remote ones by default. You need to specify that you want the new local branches to get pushed up.

Comment: If it has worked, is there any explanation for why i cannot see any commit in the list of Git-Cola?

Comment: I think I have realize it. The reason is maybe I should use Git Dag interface. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`git push local master` (or, instead of `master`, the branch you want to push)

If you only did `git init` on the other repo, it has no branches yet. So, no branch could be tracked (allowing just `git push local`).

After this command, you need not `master` at the end, because `master` now exists on `local`.

Comment: should i use `git init --bare`?

Comment: It is recommended (but not mandatory) that only bare repositories accept pushes. The log tells you how to do it. But I recommend only pushing to bare repositories (created with `git init --bare`).