# How can I change the remote (hosted) repo to which my workstation (local) repo pushes information?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I forked a project from GitHub.

From my workstation, I wish to be able to push to my Gitlab, i.e.,

```
git push
```

Here is what I get on my workstation thus far:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/OWASP/railsgoat.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/OWASP/railsgoat.git (push)
```

I think it will be a success when it instead states, for my purposes:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/OWASP/railsgoat.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/myName/railsgoat.git (push)
```

I did try looking at the documentation, however the solution as of yet evades me:

```
git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
git remote set-url --add [--push] <name> <newurl>
git remote set-url --delete [--push] <name> <url>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's rather awkward to have separate fetch and push URLs for same remote (you can do it, but it's not the typical way to achieve what you're asking for). Typically you'd add another remote, and then push to that remote.

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/myName/railsgoat.git
git remote add upstream https://github.com/OWASP/railsgoat.git
```

then you will use

```
git fetch upstream
```

to get changes from upstream repo and

```
git push origin
```

to push to your fork.

The names `upstream` and `origin` are not set in stone, though these are typical names used by the community. You can name `upstream` something else, it's just an identifier. `origin` is the name of remote given to the one from which you originally cloned.

The convention is to use `origin` for something you control (your fork), and `upstream` for something you don't control (central repo).

Then, the next concept is the "upstream branch" for a given branch (the naming is confusing).

Basically, `git push` needs to know to which branch you want to push from and to (git is overly flexible in this case which can be daunting at the beginning).

Say you want to push from `master` to `origin/master`, and you always want `git push` in the future (when in `master`) to do the same, you'd do:

```
git push -u origin master
```

(`-u` is a shorthand for `--set-upstream`, which you can later edit via `--set-upstream-to`, which makes git remember that the branch you push to right now is the default branch to be used in the future).

Once done, you can in the future use just

```
git push
```

One more note, if for some reason you're using git 1.x still, it's recommended to execute this

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

to change the behavior of what `git push` does (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0))

---

To do the exact thing you were asking for, you'd do

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://gitlab.com/myName/railsgoat.git
```

Comment: I don't think they really want to pull from upstream and push to the fork, I'd suggest to edit your answer to have the last part first, because that's the right answer for most people.

Answer (score 1):

you should add a new remote host with

```
git remote add newHostName  https://gitlab.com/myName/railsgoat.git
```

and then

```
git push newHostName branchname
```

Comment: Hi, what is newHostName? Is it Gitlab?

Comment: it is whatever you want, default is origin but here it is already taken so you need to use another one