# How git push current branch to another remote/origin?

Tags: git

My .git/config:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:nfpyfzyf/test.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

My local branches:

```
                     HEAD
                     |
                 F---G  feature**current branch
                /
       C---D---E develop
      /          
 A---B  master
```

I'm now in feature branch, and want to push to remote. What is the current command, is it`git push origin feature`? What will happen if I do `git push`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To push a specific branch, run `git push <remote> <branch>`. In your case, your only defined remote is `origin`, and you want to push your `feature` branch, so that makes

```
$ git push origin feature
```

The [“Examples” section of the `git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_examples) describes what happens if you run `git push` with no other arguments.

> `git push`
>
> Works like `git push <remote>`, where  is the current branch’s remote (or `origin`, if no remote is configured for the current branch).

Given the configuration in your question, your `feature` branch does not have a remote configured, so the above invocation is equivalent to the next example.

> `git push origin`
>
> Without additional configuration, works like `git push origin :` …

Following the daisy chain, we see that this is equivalent to

> `git push origin :`
>
> Push “matching” branches to origin. See  in the [OPTIONS](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#OPTIONS) section above for a description of "matching" branches.

The rules for matching branches are

> The special refspec `:` (or `+:` to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs `git` to push “matching” branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side. This is the default operation mode if no explicit refspec is found (that is neither on the command line nor in any Push line of the corresponding remotes file—see below) and no `push.default` configuration variable is set.

In your case, the only matching branch is `master`, so `git push` will push that branch and exit.

Answer (score 2):

`git push origin $FEATURE` is certainly correct, and will get you what you want.  However, I often use:

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

This will push up my current branch, using the branch name, so I don't have to type it out explicitly on the command line.  As mentioned in one of the other answers, `-u` will set the upstream so that a plain `git push` will work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `git push origin feature` is the right and explicit command.

What happens when you do `git push` without arguments is influenced by your configuration. The configuration variable `push.default` tells git what to do in this case. Check the man-page (`git config --help` and search for `push.default`) for more information. Just so much, there are several possibilities: `nothing`, `matching`, `upstream`, `simple` and `current`.

Also [What is the difference between git push.default=current and push.default=upstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872984/what-is-the-difference-between-git-push-default-current-and-push-default-upstrea) can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible way to do,

```
git push --set-upstream origin refs/heads/[your_local_branch_name]:refs/heads/[remote_branch_name_you_want]
```

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin feature` is correct. If you do just `git push` it will probably say something like this:

```
fatal: The current branch feature has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin feature
```

After you have used the `--set-upstream` (or just -u), simple `git push` will work

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you can use

```
git flow feature publish $FEATURE
```

to push the branch to your remote and create it remote.

It's equal to do a simple

```
git push origin $FEATURE
```

If you're simply doing a `git push` it depends on your configuration what happens - in my configuration it pushes all remotely existing branches.