# Is it possible to push changes to master branch while in another branch

Tags: git, git-branch

While we are working in different branches in git repo is it possible to accidentally push your changes from a branch say **demo** to **master**. I do know in order to bring the changes to master branch we have to do a merge the require branch to the master.

Sometimes when I push to a branch I have these doubt if I'll push it to master accidentally so just to clear that up...

Comment: What do you mean by `push to a branch`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How git push other branch to remote/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166713/how-git-push-other-branch-to-remote-origin)

Comment: My understand is that you cannot push to the wrong branch in your remote by accident - unless of course you add in the relevant flags to forcefully do it.

Comment: We need to know exactly what you expect to happen when you "push changes to master branch" means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 git push origin  local-branch-name:remote-branch-name
```

In this case, it should be:

```
 git push origin  demo:master
```

If you're using gitlab/github, you can set `master` branch as `protected` to avoid pushing some branch to master accidentally

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin master
```

This pushes any branch you are on to the master branch in the origin repository.

the shortcut

```
git push
```

only works, if the current branch is linked to some remote branch via `--set-upstream`. For example with

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Note: There are more ways to set an upstream branch

---

It is perfectly possible to accidentally push to a wrong branch. For example when you were tracking a wrong branch, or because there was a typo in the push-command, or because you forgot what branch you were on.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry

Because if you are in  other branch you made changes and unfortunately  pushed to master

**Ex:** Your in **slave** branch you pushed to master  (`git push orgin master`)

It will show **Everything up-to-date**

If you push recursively also (`git push -u origin master`)  master branch  won't affect (**If you are in other branch only**)

> **Master branch wont change until unless you merge with other branch's or till changes made in  master**

```
                                      **cool**
```