# How can I configure git to default push my current branch to the origin?

Tags: git

Is there a way to configure git to default push my current branch to the origin?

E.g., I want to do:

```
git push origin
```

And have it push whatever branch I've currently checked out to the upstream origin.

Comment: Did you try Google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch

Comment: I did, and saw the post you linked. I'm confused on what's considered 'upstream' though.  Is that the branch I've branched off of, or is that the true 'upstream repo'?

Comment: `upstream` pushes "the current branch to **its** upstream branch", i.e. the upstream tracking branch. `current` does something similar but assumes the upstream branch has the same name as the current one. There's a good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872984/what-is-the-difference-between-git-push-default-current-and-push-default-upstrea

Comment: So I did:  git push -u origin mybranch ... but I think that's not what I want. Is there a way to undo that?  When I set the push config, and tried to do git push it just said 'branch has no upstream branch'.

Answer (score 1):

Set `push.default` to `tracking`.

```
$ git config --global push.default tracking
```

Now `git push` pushes only the branch you're currently on, assume an upstream branch has been configured (see `git branch --set-upstream`).